# Working out parcel direction

Tags: direction, os-mastermap

I am looking at applying a direction indicator to land parcels and houses (in MasterMap).

Effectively, I am looking at applying a direction indicator to the land and the buildings associated to the land (NW-SE, N-S, E-W etc).  Is there an easy way to do this?

I guess you'd need to also find the direction of the road it was situated on for completeness?

Comment: Would you mind explaining what a "direction indicator" might be?

Comment: For users outside the UK - MasterMap is a product from Ordnance Survey - http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/os-mastermap/topography-layer/index.html

Comment: @whuber What I mean by this, is its aspect, as such, which way does the front and rear of the property face; is it NE-SW lying, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ITN (Integrated Transport Network) has line direction for the ROADS

http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/os-mastermap/itn-layer/index.html

but for houses/land parcels there is no way - you can add an arrow direction to the digitised line but that will only be the direction the operator drew the original linework to make the parcel polygon.

possible workaround: create a centroid of the parcel and apply a direction arrow to that?

This can be done in ArcGIS
Calculate Polygon Main Angle (Cartography)

Calculates the dominant angles of input polygon features and assigns the values to a specified field in the feature class

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//007000000028000000.htm